# WebServer and Database server hosted on seperate instances of Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am planning to run a web-application and expecting a traffic of around 100 to 200 users.

Currently I have set up single Small instance on Amazon. This instance consist of everything – the Webserver(Apache) , the Database Server(MySQL) and the IMAP server( Dovcot). I am thinking of moving out my database server out of this instance and create a separate instance for it. Now my question is –

- Do I get latency while communication between my webserver and Database server( Both hosted on separate instances on Amazon )
- If yes, what is the standard way to overcome this ? ( or Do I need to set up a Virtual Private Cloud ?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course there will be latency when communicating between separate machines. If they are both in the same availability zone it will be extremely low, typically what you'd expect for two servers on the same LAN.

If they are in different availability zones in the same region, expect a latency on the order of 2-3ms (per information provided at the 2012 AWS re:Invent conference). That's still quite low.

Using a VPC will not affect latency. That does not give you different physical connections between instances, just virtual isolation.

Finally, consider using Amazon's RDB (Relational Database Service) instead of a dedicated EC2 instance for your MySql database. The cost is about the same, and Amazon takes care of the housekeeping.

Comment: RDS doesn't give SUPER permissions. You cannot edit my.cnf which matters a lot.

Answer (score 10):

If you want your architecture to scale you should separate your web server from your database server.

The low latency that you will pay (~1-2ms even between multiple availability zone), will give you better performance as you can scale each tier separately.

- You can add small (even micro) instances to handle more web requests behind a [load balancer](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/), without the need to duplicate an instance that has to have a database as well
- You can add [auto-scale](http://aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/) group for your web server that will automatically scale your web server tier, based on usage load
- You can scale up your DB instance, to have more memory, getting a better cache hit
- You can add [Elastic Cache](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/) between your web server and your database
- You can use [Amazon RDS](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/) as a managed database service, which remove the need for an instance for the database at all (you will pay only for the actual usage of the database in RDS)

Another benefit that you can have is better security on your database. If your database is on a separate instance, you can prevent access to it from the internet. You can use a [security group](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html) that allows only sql connection from your web server and not http connection from the internet.

This configuration can run in a regular EC2 environment, without the usage of VPC. You can certainly add VPC for an even more control environment, without additional cost nor much increased complexity.

In short, for scalability and high availability you should separate your tiers (web and DB). You will probably also find yourself saving on cost as well.

Answer (score 4):

> Do I get latency while communication between my webserver and Database server( Both hosted on separate instances on Amazon )

Yes, but it's rather insignificant compared to the benefits gained by separating the roles.

> If yes, what is the standard way to overcome this ? ( or Do I need to set up a Virtual Private Cloud ?)

VPC increases security and ease of management of the resources, it does not affect performance.  A latency of a millisecond or two isn't normally problematic for a SQL database.  Writes are transactional so data isn't accessible to other requests until it's 100% completed and committed. I/O throughput and availability are much more of a concern, which is why separating the database and the application is important.

I'd highly recommend that you take a look at RDS, which is AWS's version of a managed MySQL, Oracle, or MS SQL Server database server.  This will allow you to easily setup and manage your database, including cross-availability zone replication and automated backups.  I also wrote [a blog post yesterday](http://www.jamiebegin.com/migrating-to-aws-developers-checklist/) that's fairly relevant to your question.

Comment: I would echo the thought about using RDS for your database.  Really unless you have very specific MySQL needs (clustering, multi-master replication, etc.) and you want to set up a database in AWS, you should first and foremost consider RDS.